# C# Get Version Number of Font

Tags: c#, windows, fonts, truetype

How does one get the actual version number of a font in C#? In my case, I need to know if version 6.06 of the Segoe UI Symbol font is installed.

Comment: Don't use FileVersionInfo, fonts don't have a version resource.  You need to read the fontRevision field from the `head` table.  Reading TrueType tables is not great joy, just make it a prerequisite.  Or check if you are running on Windows 8.

Comment: Is there a way to do it through interop?

Comment: GetFontData() helps a wee bit.  I'd recommend keeping your eye on the ball, what exactly are you going to do when you find out the machine doesn't have the font?  It isn't exactly very likely you'll want to write the code to draw these symbols yourself.

Comment: I'm not seeing version info from GetFontData. I'm substituting from the FontAwesome font on older systems. They don't look as good but work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to see the version of a font file from within C#, you can only check installed fonts by name, so...

I would get the name and hash of the correct file and compare that to the target system:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

...

```
const string fontFileName = "seguisym.ttf";
const string fontHash = "/O7kUQinASYq8BG6dSY4YXkXQcbCeZQOmAcaWQqPP60OcgbGpXR5+yNug0pceicfHpjxV+6sdmy1j8Np2VIbOQ==";

static bool FontIsInstalled()
{
    string fontPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), fontFileName);
    if (!File.Exists(fontPath)) return false;
    using (SHA512Managed sha = new SHA512Managed())
    {
        return fontHash.Equals(Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(fontPath))));
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please update your fontfileName as it's invalid it should be 'segoeui.ttf'

Comment: @JulieShannon Actually he asked for Segoe UI Symbol, so I updated for that instead.

Comment: This only works for a specific version. I'm looking for a >= type of comparison. Interesting approach however.

Comment: @MikeWard OK, well, is it possible to get hashes for all of the versions OLDER than the one you need and then instead check if it's one of the versions that's not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it was introduced more recently, but by now it's possible to get the version of a font for a specific typeface via `TryGetGlyphTypeface()`.

Example for Segoe UI:

```
var segoe = new FontFamily("Segoe UI");
var typeface = new Typeface(segoe, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal);
var isGlyphTypeface = typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out var glyph);
if(isGlyphTypeface)
{
  Console.WriteLine(glyph.Version);
}
```